# Webpack does not recognize JSX when a rule array is set in config

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

This is my webpack configuration:

```
const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: './src/entry.jsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
        ],
        // rules: [],
    }
};
```

Notice that the rule array is commented out.

When I build webpack with the following JS:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

It works just fine. But when I uncomment the rules array, I'm given the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/entry.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| ReactDOM.render(
|     <h1>Hello, World!</h1>,
|     document.getElementById('app')
| );
```

But with the rule array commented out, it gives me this:

```
> webpack

Hash: 96711291c47522e3cd46
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 1221ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  727 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [14] ./src/entry.jsx 484 bytes {0} [built]
    + 26 hidden modules
```

With no errors.

I need that rule array because I have some dependencies that need me to add things to that array.

Comment: I suppose you should simply rename loaders to rules, because there is no loaders section anymore in the docs for v3

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/

Comment: Please comment your answer so I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: yes I've replied below, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the currect docs on webpack v3 (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/), the module section doesn't have a `loaders` key anymore, but only `rules`.

I suspect in your case `loaders` overwrite `rules` due to backwards compatibility with older versions of webpack

So renaming loaders to rules should be sufficient to solve the problem

Good luck